# "export 'ɵb' was not found in ___" error when migrating angular components from version 8 to 9

Tags: angular, npm, migration

I'm migrating an Angular component suite from version 8 to 9.
I followed all the [steps indicated](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.2-9.1) in the official documentation. The sample application included in the components project works normally after the migration.

But then the following error occurs in the application when I try to use this component:

> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/@pucomex-ng-infra/pucx-components/fesm2015/pucomex-ng-infra-pucx-components.js 5172:124-126 "export 'ɵb' was not found in
> '@pucomex-ng-infra/pucx-platform-client'

I noticed that there are some javascript files in the dist folder that have structures starting with the character 'ɵ' (theta in Greek), followed by other letters. I already know that this letter is used by Angular to indicate some private method to the framework that should not be called directly by the user.

When analyzing the difference in the generated js files, I noticed that this also occurs at some points in Angular 8 but they are usually referred to in another way (and they did not cause an error in the application call):

```
{ ..., PucxAjudaComponent as ɵa, PucxFieldsetComponent as ɵb,...}
```

In Angular 9, it usually appears as follows:

```
{ ..., MsgCenterService, ɵb,... }
```

So, does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem or has experienced something similar?